# Custom image in Angular.ui bootstrap rating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the `rating` directive of angular bootstrap ui. How can I use a custom image as icon and not a glyphicon?

Comment: What happens if you provide a custom style class to `state-on`?

Comment: You can always customise the default template to display whatever you want: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#customize-templates

Comment: Sorry, probably it's me being stupid, but could you post a CSS snippet where you actually set a custom image for the state-on and state-off? I tried <pre>.blueStar {
    background-image: url('/images/star-blue.gif');
}</pre> but it does not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me.

---CSS

```
    .orange-star { 
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      background-size: contain;
      background-image: url("{!$Resource.OrangeStar}");
    }
    .white-star {
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      background-size: contain;
      background-image: url("{!$Resource.Whitestar}");
    }
```

---- HTML -----

```
<rating ng-model="rate" max="4" state-on="'orange-star'" state-off="'white-star'"> </rating>
```